# Не получается импортировать Router из aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram, aiogram-3.x

изучаю aiogram, дошел до функции роутеров, но не получается их импортировать
[image: Просто подчеркивается красным]

Версия aiogram 3.0.0b7

[image]

В самом файле **init** версия разнится с версией написанной в pip, не знаю имеет ли это значение
[image]

Уже несколько раз переустанавливал aiogram, обновлял, ничего не помогает

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: может ты установил его в venv и не задал интерпретатор на venv или наоборот